# C# How to convert ArrayList of typed objects to a typed List?

Tags: c#, types

I have an ArrayList of objects that are of a certain type, and I need to convert this ArrayList in to a types list.  Here is my code

```
Type objType = Type.GetType(myTypeName);

ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

object myObj0 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
object myObj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
object myObj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

myArrayList.Add(myObj0);
myArrayList.Add(myObj1);
myArrayList.Add(myObj2);

Array typedArray = myArrayList.ToArray(objType);  // this is typed
object returnValue = typedArray.ToList();  // this is fake, but this is what I am looking for
```

There is no ToList() available for an Array, this is the behaviour I am looking for

```
object returnValue = typedArray.ToList();
```

So basically I have the type name as a string, I can create a Type from the name, and create a collection containing several objects typed, but how do I convert that to a List?  I am hydrating a property and when I do a SetValue my property type needs to match.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the type at compile-time, or is this dynamic?

Comment: dynamic, I am converting from JSON and I know the type as a string, and I can create the typed object array, but I need the output to be a List<myStrongType>

Comment: So... you're trying to covert an Array (typed) to a List<T>, is that right? And you have the name of "type T" stored in a string (and a Type object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, dynamic typing can help - it can perform type inference so you can call `ToList`, admittedly not as an extension method:

```
dynamic typedArray = myArrayList.ToArray(objType);    
object returnValue = Enumerable.ToList(typedArray);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use reflection:

```
object typedArray = myArrayList.ToArray(objType);   
// It really helps that we don't need to work through overloads...
MethodInfo openMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
MethodInfo genericMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(objType);
object result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { typedArray });
```

Comment: If I'm not missing something, you can't call `ToList<T>` directly on `ArrayList`, because is not generic. You should call `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` before that...

Comment: @digEmAll: I'm not - I'm calling it on `typedArray`, which is a typed array resulting from the `myArrayList.ToArray(objType)` call.

Comment: dont argue with john skeet =)

Answer (score 2):

Create a

```
List<YourType> list = new List<YourType>;
```

and then

```
list.AddRange(yourArray);
```

Comment: This won't work, since `Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I don't have <YourType> available at compile time, I am starting with a string that has the type name, and then I resolve the type as a Type

Comment: No need for `AddRange()` anyway, the `List<T>` constructor accepts an array of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Use an extenstion method: `.ToList<myType>()`

Comment: `ToList()` is generic on the *source* sequence generic type, so that call will fail since `ArrayList` isn't generic at all.

Comment: myType in my case is a Type variable, I don't have the actual type. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic `List<>` type instead.

Comment: Isn't that what he's asking? How to convert an array to a generic list?

Comment: How do I use List<> when I only have the type as a variable? Thanks.

Comment: @Jason Lavigne: Why is your type specified in a string?

Comment: @BoltClock: He isn't using generics, so my suggestion is that he does.

Comment: @Bernard, because I am converting JSON to a list of typed objects, I am able to populate the object just fine using reflection, but now I need a typed list.

Comment: @Jason Lavigne: You should have specified this as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be `List<T>` or would an `IEnumerable<T>` do?

Taking a little from Linq you could do:

```
object returnValue = myArrayList.Cast<string>();
```

Which creates the following object (assuming T = string):

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__b1`1[System.String]
```